# React Router (V6) Link works without a server request but useNavigate doesn't

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I've been using 'react-router-dom' (v6) in combination with [Microsoft Fluint UI Nav](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/nav).
Because of this I have to programmatically navigate instead of using the `<Link></Link>` element.

When I use a `<Link to="test">to test</Link>` it navigates to the requested page without a server request. But when I use this (basically an eventHandler that calls `navigate` for the redirect) :

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const navLinkGroups: INavLinkGroup[] = [
    {
      links: [{ name: 'test', url: 'test', onClick: () => navigate('test') }],
    },
  ];

return (
     <Stack><Nav groups={navLinkGroups} isOnTop={true} /></Stack>
  );
```

It does a server request when going to the 'test' page. Is this by design or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

You can reproduce it this way:

1. Create the project: `npx create-react-app my-app --template @fluentui/cra-template`
2. Edit App.tsx like:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

//UI-Components import
import { Header } from './UI-Components/Header';
// Page Import
import { TestPage } from './Pages/Test';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="test" element={<TestPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

3. Create Headers.tsx (`UI-Components` folder)
4. Add Header.tsx content:

```
import { Stack } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Stack';
import { Nav, INavLinkGroup, INavProps } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Nav';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Header = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const navLinkGroups: INavLinkGroup[] = [
    {
      links: [{ name: 'test', url: 'test', onClick: () => navigate('test') }],
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack><Nav groups={navLinkGroups} isOnTop={true} /></Stack>
      <Stack></Stack>
      <Link to="test">to test</Link>
      <Stack></Stack>
      <Stack></Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

5. Create `Test.tsx` in the `Pages` folder
6. Add content `export const TestPage = () => <div>test</div>;`
7. Now you should be able to reproduce the problem

Comment: Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Which type of Router are you using? (hashrouter, browserrouter)

Comment: Also I think it needs a leading slash, at least looking at v6 "what's new" stuff, like `navigate('/test')`

Comment: @Nikki9696 That depends. RRDv6 can use relative or absolute routing/linking. The leading `"/"` is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob mistake...
I forgot to `preventDefault()`. Fixed it like:

```
  function handleNavClick(event?: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, element?: INavLink) {
    if (event && element) {
      event.preventDefault();
      navigate(element.url);
    }
  }

  const navLinkGroups: INavLinkGroup[] = [
    {
      links: [{ name: 'test', url: 'test', onClick: (event, element) => handleNavClick(event, element) }],
    },
  ];
```